# Atomic Stress (Virial Stress) and Harmonic Springs

Tags: stress-strain, molecular-dynamics

The general context here is polymer physics.

The stress tensor in a bead-spring simulation can be easily computed using the Virial Stress (which may be named the Kirkwood formula, or the Doi-Edwards Formula depending on the person you are talking with). This formula is the following, when the particles only interact with each others :

$$\sigma_{\alpha \beta}=\frac{1}{2V}\sum_{i, j'} F_{mn\,\alpha} R_{mn\,\beta}, $$
where $V$ is the volume of the simulation box, $\vec{F}_{mn}$ is the central force acting on particle $m$ due to its interaction with particle $n$, and $\vec{R}_{mn}$ is the vector joining the centers of particle $m$ and $n$.

Let assume that I constructed a system with only harmonic springs between particles. Each particle is connected to $n_c$ neighbors and the force of a spring is simply $F=k(l-l_0)$ with $k$ the spring strength, $l$ the center to center length between two particles and $l_0$ the length at rest. In such a system, the local deformation of a spring becomes $l-l_0=l_0\epsilon$ we can estimate how scales the stress when a macroscopic deformation $\epsilon$ is imposed on $N$ beads connected together with $n_c$ springs each :

$$ \sigma \propto \frac{N\, n_c\, F\, R}{V} = \frac{N\, n_c\, k\, l_0 \epsilon\, R }{V} .$$

Here, $\epsilon = (l-l_0)/l_0$.

Hey wait, $R=l=l_0(\epsilon+1)$ and therefore

$$ \sigma \propto \frac{N \,k\, l^2_0\, \left(\epsilon^2+\epsilon \right)}{V} . $$

Ok, so this is a nice approximation of how the stress should evolve during the deformation of the spring network. However, I have found papers discussing the strain hardening of glassy polymers based on a bead-spring model implemented in such a way. My opinion here is that the quadratic dependence of the stress on the strain is only a numerical artifact of the way it is estimated. However, I have the feeling that this estimation does not account for the deformation that is actually performed on the system, for instance is it elongation ? shear ? elongation at a fixed volume ?

And especially when the volume can be written $V=V(1+\epsilon)$, the quadratic term vanishes. However, during a uni-axial elongation with a fixed volume, this quadratic behavior if the most pronounced.

Therefore, I have the following questions :

- Is my rough estimation of the scaling of the stress correct ?
- Is it normal that the stress in a spring network grows in a quadratique manner with the strain ?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: In your equation for $\sigma$, did you intend for $e$ to be the same symbol as $\epsilon$? In which case, you usually just ignore higher order terms for small displacements (linear regime).

Comment: Here $\epsilon=(l-l_0)/l_0$. I just assume that the macroscopic deformation is the same as deformation of each springs. I'm ok to say that we can ignore higher order term for $\epsilon \ll 1$ but why should we constrain to the small deformation regime ?

Comment: All materials are nonlinear with sufficiently large deformations; but math is simpler and more tractable with small deformations. Most materials become nonlinear with strains greater than a fraction of a percent (see for example [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93strain_curve))

Comment: Off course materials are non-linear, but my simple random spring network should be linear (if we neglect the fact they are going to align during an elongation, but this is only a mater of $\left\langle \cos\theta \right\rangle$). If I want to model a linear material with a model that imposes a quadratic response of my stress, while it is measured linear experimentally, I consider I'm failing at my job :)

Comment: What you've done looks fine to me, which suggests that your model simply isn't suitable for modelling the elasticity of glassy polymers at large strains...?

Comment: @lemon, I think this is the answer I was looking for :)

Comment: For large strains the equation $(l-l_0) = \varepsilon l_0$ is only approximate, the correct one would be $(l/l_0)^2 = 1+2\varepsilon$, then $l-l_0 = l_0(\varepsilon - \varepsilon^2/2 + \varepsilon^3/2 - -5\varepsilon^4/8+ \dots )$